# PHP foreach causes "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop that does something depending on the contents of an ACF repeater field (map_destinations). It works fine if there are destinations, but if there aren't I get:

> "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Here's my code:

```
$map_destinations = get_field('map_destinations', $tour_id);        
$map = array();
    foreach ($map_destinations as $map_destination) {
    $map[] = $map_destination['destination'];
}
```

I have tried various solutions but none work. The most commonly accepted method seems to be:

```
$map_destinations = get_field('map_destinations', $tour_id);        
$map = array();
if (is_array($map)) {
    foreach ($map_destinations as $map_destination) {
    $map[] = $map_destination['destination'];
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Please bear with me, I am just getting to grips with php.

Comment: `$map_destinations` is not an array :) You can find out what is it by using `var_dump($map_destinations)`

Comment: `get_field` should return an empty array even if there is no data available that a easy way out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not check for `is_array($map)`rather check for `is_array($map_destinations)`, or `!empty()`

```
$map_destinations = get_field('map_destinations', $tour_id);        
$map = array();
if (is_array($map_destinations)) {
    foreach ($map_destinations as $map_destination) {
        $map[] = $map_destination['destination'];
    }
}
```